# PHP how to get list of all defined variable?

Tags: php

How to get the list of defined variables and its values. eg `define('DS', DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR);`

How can I list all of them at the end of page to check all of them working as expected. Instead of printing all of them one by one.

I've tried `get_defined_vars()` But I'm getting all Super Global variables like below.

```
Array
(
    [GLOBALS] => Array
        (
            [GLOBALS] => Array
 *RECURSION*
            [_POST] => Array
                (
                )

            [_GET] => Array
                (
                )

            [_COOKIE] => Array
                (
                    [PHPSESSID] => tkv7odk47idt4r2ob7389tkr81
                    [CAKEPHP] => cep9tbooimh5kbhn8jovmaqgi1
                )

            [_FILES] => Array
                (
                )

            [_SERVER] => Array
```

But I want only those which I've mentioned using the `define()` statement.

Is there any way of getting it.

Comment: For the record, `define` defines *constants*, not variables.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can get this by using **[get_defined_constants](http://php.net/manual/en/function.get-defined-constants.php)**

```
$constarray = get_defined_constants(true);
foreach($constarray['user'] as $key => $val)
    eval(sprintf('$_CONSTANTS[\'%s\'] = \'%s\';', addslashes($key), addslashes($val)));
```

Answer (score 2):

To retrieve all the defined constants in php script you can use the function  get_defined_constants()

It will return an  associative array of all constants defined in php script

For more documentation about get_defined_constants please refer the below url
http://php.net/manual/en/function.get-defined-constants.php

Answer (score 1):

Use `get_defined_constants();` , refer http://php.net/manual/en/function.get-defined-constants.php

Answer (score 0):

I use this code to get all define . you can include php file and use this code

```
              include("FILE.PHP");  

              GET_ALL_define();

            function GET_ALL_define(){

                    $getdefinedconstants = get_defined_constants(true);
                    $definedvars = $getdefinedconstants['user'];

                    foreach($definedvars as $key => $value){
                        echo $key ." = ". $value . "<br>";
                    }

            }
```

or without include php file like this code .

```
          define("_A","A1");
          define("_B","B2");   
          define("_C","C3");

              GET_ALL_define();

            function GET_ALL_define(){

                    $getdefinedconstants = get_defined_constants(true);
                    $definedvars = $getdefinedconstants['user'];

                    foreach($definedvars as $key => $value){
                        echo $key ." = ". $value . "<br>";
                    }

            }
```